# How to pass auto wired dependencies as mock while unit testing a class which has constructors with arguments

Tags: java, groovy, spock

I am trying to unit test two separate classes, the constructor of one being the default constructor and the constructor of another, a constructor having some arguments. Both the classes have an autowired component, say,

```
class A {
  @Autowired
  private SomeClass someClass;
}
```

```
class B {
  @Autowired
  private SomeClass someClass;

  public B(int a, String b) {
    //method implementation
  }
}
```

I am trying to unit test these two classes and for the first one if I create the class object using

```
def mockedSomeClass = Mock(SomeClass)
def a = new A(someClass:mockedSomeClass)
```

it works fine.

But for the second class , I have tried passing the constructor arguments and the dependencies required through different syntaxes

like

```
def mockedSomeClass = Mock(SomeClass)
def b = new B(10, "g", someClass:mockedSomeClass)
```

and

```
def b = new B(someClass:mockedSomeClass, 10, "g")
```

and

```
def b = new B(10, "g")(someClass:mockedSomeClass)
```

All these were trial and error as I could not find any documentation similar to this particular case.

Any help on how to correctly do this would be highly appreciated

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using Mockito?

Comment: @Madhu Bhat I am using Spock

Comment: Hi @Krishna. If my or any other answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. Of course, there is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In class A, calling the constructor like this

```
new A(someClass:mockedSomeClass)
```

works fine, because in groovy, the default constructor that is generated implicitly, supports setting the value of any field by [passing a named parameter](http://groovy-lang.org/style-guide.html#_initializing_beans_with_named_parameters_and_the_default_constructor) which is supported only in a default constructor. You had one field (someClass) which you had passed through the constructor, which was OK.

However, in class B you have an explicit constructor with two arguments. Note that you can call this constructor only with these specified two arguments (i.e. int a, String b) since it's explicitly defined like that. Remember that this is not a default constructor as in class A, so it doesn't automatically support setting a field by passing a named parameter.

Long story short, to make it work, you have to explicitly specify also the third argument:

```
class B{

@Autowired
private SomeClass someClass;

public B(int a,String b, SomeClass someClass)
{
    //method implementation
    this.someClass = someClass;
}
```

And then you can call it like this:

```
def b=new B(10, "g", mockedSomeClass)
```

**An alternative approach**:

The approach from above is the one I would prefer since it is a bit cleaner. The reason is that it is better to have all mandatory dependencies in the constructor to avoid confusion.

However, if for some reason it's not OK for you to change the Java source code, you can also solve it by creating the object like this:

```
def b=new B(10, "g")
b.someClass = mockedSomeClass
```

In the above example, we are first creating the object by calling the explicit constructor of class B, which takes 2 parameters. Then we set the *someClass* field  (this looks like assigning the private field manually but in fact  we are setting it through the setter which is generated automatically in groovy, you can read about the implicit getter and setters here: http://groovy-lang.org/style-guide.html#_getters_and_setters ).

Comment: Thank you for the response. I am not able to fully understand the logic here. For class A, even though the constructor was default constructor (without argument), it was possible to create the object by passing the dependency. For class B, why do we need to change the constructor altogether.

Comment: @Krishna It's because the constructor of class B, that you are using, is not a default constructor like the one in class A. You can pass the value for any field in a default constructor, but not in an explicit constructor. In an explicit constructor, you have to add it explicitly as a parameter and assign the field manually.

Comment: @Krishna I wanted to say, this works only in a default constructor (which is generated implicitly), not in an explicit constructor (a constructor defined manually). Do you understand it now?

Comment: @mprev0- Yes,Thanks.So the only option  is changing the Java source code? :(

Comment: @Krishna there is actually another option, I added it now to the answer. Sorry, I didn't know that you want to avoid changing the Java source code, the first one I proposed is a cleaner approach, but if changing the Java code is not an option,  the other one will be fine as well!